# Spark-submit job with Airflow: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: pyspark, airflow

I need to seek your advice on what could be the root cause here.
Please pardon my knowledge as I'm a beginner in using Airflow as well as using pyspark.

Our spark cluster has 1 master, 2 worker and 2 data nodes.
Airflow is running on the master node.

I have a spark-submit job which can be run successfully **(*)** by using command:

```
sh spark-submit.sh job.py
```

This job basically reads from Hadoop, does some transformation & aggregation then convert back into pandas for convenient pandas.melt() as well as pandas.to_csv() naming.

This same command when triggered in Airflow dag with as a Bash-operator will result in:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

during the write operation - pd_df.to_csv(). I realized that any os path and directory functions will also fail. I understand that the worker nodes have different folder structure than master node but why would my job in **(*)** succeeds if that was the root cause? I was under the impression that when I do spark_df.toPandas(), all data would be gathered in master node and "local" python as well as "local" folder structure will be used.

The only working way to get output right now is to use spark_df.write.

At this point I suspect there maybe some configuration issue with our Airflow setup.

I also wish to highlight that I have to copy **all** my codes, their dependencies and dag.py to worker nodes else it won't work either. As an user, I find this very strange. Why wouldn't Airflow help distribute the code to worker nodes?

Thank you in advance and I appreciate any help I could get.

---

EDIT:
Adding on more info:

- File structure & Where the spark job is & Where the Airflow DAG is located
- How the Operator looks like

File structure:

```
+ /var/lib/airflow/dags
| dag.py
| + scripts/
| | + proj_a/
| | | spark-submit.sh
| | | job.py
```

The exact copy of folder structure and files are made to the worker nodes.

operator in "dag.py"

```
task_1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='job',
    bash_command='sh /var/lib/airflow/dags/scripts/proj_a/spark-submit.sh /var/lib/airflow/dags/scripts/proj_a/job.py',
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Could you share the file structure? Where is the Airflow DAG located, how does the Operator look like, where is the spark job?

Comment: @PhilippJohannis Hi, I just added the info :D